# Definition of a Derivative problem

Tags: calculus

> $$f(x) =\begin{cases}
> 2x-2 & x< 3\\
> 2x-4 & x\geq 3
> \end{cases}$$

> **6:** Let $f$ be the piecewise linear function defined above. Which of the following statements are true?

> **I:** $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}=2$$

> **II:** $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}=2$$

> **III:** $f'(3)=2$

> **(A):** None   **(B):** *II* only   **(C):** *I* and *II* only    **(D):** *I*, *II*, and *III*

The answer key for this problem says that the answer is **B**, but I can't seem to understand why. Shouldn't it be **C**? The derivative of this function when $x$ is just less than and just greater than $3$ is $2$ either way, right?

Comment: You should actually compute the limits in I,II.

Comment: Note that when you compute I the $f(3)$ is still evaluated using the expression $2x-4$, since the input is $3$ which is greater than or equal to $3$. Therefore, you get $\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{2(3+h)-2-(2\cdot 3-4)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{2h+2}{h}=-\infty$.

Comment: Ohh, wait, it's because f(3) is always 2(3) - 4 = 2 for both I and II right?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that for any $\epsilon > 0$ you have $f'(3 - \epsilon) = f'(3 + \epsilon) = 2$. However, it is very important to look at the limits actually described, noting in particular that by the function's definition $f(3) = 2$. So if we calculate the limit in I:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(3 + h) - f(3)}{h} & = & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{(2(3 + h) - 2) - 2}{h} && \text{Since } h < 0, 3+h<3 \\
& = & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{6 + 2h - 4}{h} \\
& = & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{2h + 2}{h}
\end{eqnarray}$$

and this limit *does not exist*. Which means that $f$ does not have a left derivative at $x = 3$, and so it has no derivative.

Answer (score 0):

$f(3)=2x-4$; so when you plug this into the limits in both I and II, II gives you $2$ as expected but you get $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^{-}}\dfrac{6+2h-2-6+4}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^{-}}\dfrac{2h+2}{h}$$ for I, which doesn't quite reduce to $2$.

I'm guessing what you did was plug in $f(3)=2\times 3-2$ for I and find the limits to be the same.